# Logarithm Calculation with Windows 7 Calculator

Tags: windows, math, calculator, scientific-computing, logarithm

I would like to use the **Windows Calculator** in Scientific Mode in order solve a very basic Logarithm equation but, unfortunately, I couldn't do that.

Here is the problem:

```
log_5 125=?
```

Thank you very much for your help...

Well, I know it equals to "3", but, how can I use the Windows Calculator to get computed that equation for example?

Comment: Flagged this for moving to superuser.com

Answer (score 60):

You can calculate a logarithm in a given base by calculating two logarithms in an arbitrary base, using the following equation:

```
log_b (x) = log_k (x) / log_k (b)
```

As the windows calculator got a ln button, which stands for the natural logarithm (that is, log in basis e,) then you can press 125, ln, /, 5, ln, and get the desired result.

For bonus points, here is why the above equation holds:

- Let a<sup>b</sup> = c. Remember that this sets b = log_a (c).
- Take log_k of both sides of the first equation. We get: log_k (a<sup>b</sup>) = log_k (c)
- Using the logarithmic identity log (x<sup>y</sup>) = y * log (x), we get b * log_k (a) = log_k (c)
- Hence b = log_k (c) / log_k (a).
- From the first step, we have b = log_a (c), hence log_a (c) = log_k (c) / log_k (a). QED.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm giving it a try now...

Comment: You're welcome. Just notice the typo I made when listing the operations in the calculator (wrote 25 instead of 5!)

Comment: is there not a log_x(y) button on the calculator?